# NPM Audit List Only Critical Severity Vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-audit

How critical severity vulnerabilities can be listed in a node.js project on windows platform?

I have tried:

> npm audit --audit-level=critical

but it still lists all vulnerabilities.